# In the BBC Merlin finale, when he loses this does he also lose this?

Tags: merlin, merlin-bbc

Massive Spoiler Alert: (kinda) In the next-to-last episode of the BBC Show Merlin,

> Morgana contrives a way to rob Merlin of his magic.

When this happens, does he also lose his ability to speak with dragons? If not, then why didn't he have the dragon take him to the valley of the fallen kings? Or at least consult with him on how to

> get back his magic?

Comment: It's hard to say.  There have been plenty of times when I thought, "Why doesn't he just ride the dragon?", but then he doesn't.

Comment: Arthur still hated Magic then and was hating Merlin as well during the trip for 1. having magic and 2. being the same old man who Arthur believed killed Uthur (speculation as Arthur seemed to not recogize him), if Merlin yelled out for the **same dragon which attacked Camelot** as if commanding it to give them a ride i doubt any chance of Arthur and Merlin reconciling would be gone.

Answer (score 2):

I believe not, and would like to think that being a Warlock/Wizard is different from being a Dragon Lord.

When Merlins father is first mentioned, he is referred to as a Dragon Lord. *Not* a Sorcerer or Wizard or Warlock, but specifically a Dragon Lord. This leads me to believe that just like Gaius, Dragon Lords cannot natively use magic, but instead must learn it.

So it would seem that Merlin would not lose his power over Dragons. However, given that he was trapped in a cave, there wasn't much point in calling Kilgarrah, as he simply would not be able to reach Merlin.

Comment: I think a dragon is always useful to have nearby, but that's just my opinion

Comment: @childcat15 - True. but then again, he doesn't call the Dragon except very extreme cases. Even when he himself is in danger.

Answer (score 0):

The show doesn't spell out the magic system so is speculation.  When Merlin calls the dragon, magic must be involved because the dragon is not within ear shot.  But Merlin is a Dragon Lord because his father is one, so I think that it is a kind of magic that is activated by a genetic component (like magic in the Deryni books by Katherine Kurtz).  So is this magic different than "regular" magic?  It seems the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

About the dragon lord answer Merlin's father reveals that they are born with the power to speak with dragons but you also have to work at it and about the dragon it could be that the dragon wouldn't go because he knew that this was such an important event that he shouldn't have intervened

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this answers the question (**does Merlin lose his ability to speak with dragons?**) Answers here are expected to actually answer the original post, not just provide additional commentary. You might like to take our [tour] to get a better idea of how the site works.